# How do I offset UILabel text alignment?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, text-alignment

I am trying to offset the center starting point for a UILabel. The problem that I am facing is that I can't make the label text grow from a point that is offset from center until it reaches one end of the label. Then, I want the text to shift one character to the left with each additional added character until it reaches the the other end. Then it would be acceptable for the text to truncate with an ellipses.

So far, my code looks like this but I don't know where to go from here.

```
    private let amountLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .blue
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
```

[image]

Comment: What does "I can't the label text to grow from a point that is offset from center until it reaches one end of the label. Then, I want the text to shit one character to the left with each additional added character until it reaches the the other end." mean?

Comment: Sorry, let me edit that.

Comment: Post some example pics or diagrams of what you want.

Comment: Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Not user if got what you mean, but I believe you problem can be easily solved by just increasing the UILabel's leading constraint.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you put the `UILabel` into a container view, center horizontally with the offset you want, but set its priority lower than the compression resistance., e.g. 750, compression resistance 999. Then create a trailing constraint >= with priority 1000, and leading constraint >= priority 1000. In that way centering will be the weakest constraint and as the text grows it will shift to the left until it reaches the leading.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]